# How to get multiple sender ID in FCM?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

For receiving messages from multiple senders, [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#receiving-messages-from-multiple-senders) says:

> To enable this feature, make sure you have each sender's sender ID.

and for sender ID [it](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#credentials) says:

> Sender ID: A unique numerical value created when you create your Firebase project, available in the Cloud Messaging tab of the Firebase console Settings pane. The sender ID is used to identify each sender that can send messages to the client app.

As I understood, there can be only one sender ID for a Firebase project, so how can I get multiple sender ID for sending notifications from multiple senders?